# How are models in Django unittests synced to database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

In Django, you can create models only for testing by creating them in your `tests` module:

```
from django.db import models
from django.test import TestCase

class TestModel(models.Model):
    # attributes

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        # do something with TestModel
```

Now what I would like to know, how the `syncdb` command knows, that this model also has to be synced to database.

I searched through Django's code, but I could not find any obvious code doing this. All code related to `syncdb` only works with the `models` modules inside the apps, but never looks into the `tests` module.

---

**Edit:** Just to clear things up a little bit: The target of my question is, how `syncdb` comes to create the normal models from the app's `models` module *and* those from `tests` module if a test is running instead of only syncing those from `models` module.

The target is not to create instances for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Django creates a new blank database on the fly to run your tests, so if you have models just for testing, they don't need to be added to your main database by syncdb.

This is discussed in the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: Yeah that is what is happening, but where is the code, that tells `syncdb` to also sync the models created or referenced in `tests` module in addition to those from `models` module?

Answer (score -1):

Use fixtures. Django will create test_database and put all your models to this database and adds testing data(described in fixtures). 
See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models).

Also, in your tests.py add something like this

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class MyTest(TestCase):
    fixtures=["fixture.yaml","fixture.json"]

    def setUp(self):
        celf.c = Client()        

    def test_something(self):
        resp = self.client.get("/")
        self.assertContains(resp,"Something from fixtures.")
```

`Something from your fixture` is string that must be printed on page by `"/"` view function.
This is the way I use to test my views and models.
Also, you can dump your data from existing development db, use [manage.py dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model).

Good luck.

Comment: The target is not to create instances for test, but just finding the code, that tells `syncdb` to also sync those testing models.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then see the other answer.